# Vue JS Multiple filters, one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I'm currently struggling to get the right things going with my code. I'm trying to create some dynamically generated objects based on an array (that's done). I've implemented a search function, and had a working filter (just one) at one point. I've tried chaining the filters but that failed :') I need to be able to search, and filter the array based on what the user chooses out of the 3 categories (topic, price, reviewstars), could be just one or two, or all.

I've been struggling with this for the better part of the last 12 hours D: Just literally have no idea how to go about this with the way that I implemented everything :/
Main code below:

```js
let classes = {
  menu: [
    { topic: 'math', location: 'adadadas', price: 80, length: "120", time: "9:00", reviewStars: "3" },
    { topic: 'math', location: 'dsadassa', price: 90, length: "70", time: "11:00", reviewStars: "4" },
    { topic: 'math', location: 'dadass', price: 120, length: "30", time: "14:00", reviewStars: "1" },
    { topic: 'english', location: 'dasdsadas', price: 110, length: "45", time: "13:00", reviewStars: "2" },
    { topic: 'english', location: 'fsafasf', price: 90, length: "75", time: "11:00", reviewStars: "4" },
    { topic: 'english', location: 'fafasa', price: 90, length: "100", time: "17:00", reviewStars: "2" },
    { topic: 'english', location: 'fsasada', price: 130, length: "90", time: "15:00", reviewStars: "3" },
    { topic: 'piano', location: 'dsadsadsads', price: 120, length: "", time: "50", time: "13:00", reviewStars: "4" },
    { topic: 'piano', location: 'dsadasddsadsadas', price: 140, length: "40", time: "12:00", reviewStars: "1" }
  ],
  input: {
    topic: '',
    location: 'All',
    topics: 'All',
    price: 'All',
    review: 'All'
  },
  newAry: [],
  otherAry: [],
  filterText: null
};


var searchBar = new Vue({
  el: '#searchBar',
  data: classes,
  computed: {
    menuArray() {
      let vm = this
      let array = new Set()
      vm.menu.forEach(function (item) {
        array.add(item.location)
      })
      console.log(array)
      return vm.newAry = Array.from(array)

    },

    menuArrayReview() {
      let vm = this
      let array = new Set()
      vm.menu.forEach(function (item) {
        array.add(item.reviewStars)
      })
      console.log(array)
      return vm.newAry = Array.from(array)

    },
    menuArrayTopic() {
      let vm = this
      let array = new Set()
      vm.menu.forEach(function (item) {
        array.add(item.topic)
      })
      console.log(array)
      return vm.newAry = Array.from(array)

    },
    menuArrayPrice() {
      let vm = this
      let array = new Set()
      vm.menu.forEach(function (item) {
        array.add(item.price)
      })
      console.log(array)
      return vm.newAry = Array.from(array)

    },

    filterTypeTopic() {
      let vm = this
      if (vm.input.topic !== 'All') {
        return vm.otherAry.filter(function (item) {
          return item.topic === vm.input.topic
        })
      } else {
        return vm.otherAry
      }
    },

    filterTypePrice() {
      let vm = this
      if (vm.input.price !== 'All') {
        return vm.otherAry.filter(function (item) {
          return item.price === vm.input.price
        })
      } else {
        return vm.otherAry
      }
    },

    filterTypeReviews() {
      let vm = this
      if (vm.input.review !== 'All') {
        return vm.otherAry.filter(function (item) {
          return item.reviewStars === vm.input.review
        })
      } else {
        return vm.otherAry
      }
    },

    filterAryTopic() {
      let vm = this
      if (vm.input.topic) {
        return vm.filterTypeTopic().filter(function (item) {
          let content = item.topic.toLowerCase()
          let keyword = vm.input.topic.toLowerCase()
          return content.indexOf(keyword) !== -1
        })
      } else {
        return vm.filterTypeTopic
      }

    },

    filterAryPrice() {
      let vm = this
      if (vm.input.price) {
        return vm.filterTypePrice.filter(function (item) {
          let content = item.price.toLowerCase()
          let keyword = vm.input.price.toLowerCase()
          return content.indexOf(keyword) !== -1
        })
      } else {
        return vm.filterTypePrice
      }

    },

    filterAryReviews() {
      let vm = this
      if (vm.input.review) {
        return vm.filterTypeReviews().filter(function (item) {
          let content = item.reviewStars.toLowerCase()
          let keyword = vm.input.review.toLowerCase()
          return content.indexOf(keyword) !== -1
        })
      } else {
        vm.menu = vm.filterTypeReviews()
      }
    },

    filterType() {
      let vm = this
      if (vm.input.location !== 'All') {
        return vm.otherAry.filter(function (item) {
          return item.location === vm.input.location
        })
      } else {
        return vm.menu
      }
    },

    filterAry() {
      let vm = this
      if (vm.input.topic) {
        return vm.filterType.filter(function (item) {
            let content = item.topic.toLowerCase()
          let keyword = vm.input.topic.toLowerCase()
          return content.indexOf(keyword) !== -1
        })
      } else {
        return vm.filterType
      }
    },


    getAry() {
      let vm = this
      return vm.otherAry
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    newAry = classes;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="searchBar">
    <div class="display-3 text-center my-5 text-secondary">Activities!  </div>
    <div class="container w-75">
      <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div>
            <select name=""  class="form-control" v-model.trim="input.price">
              <option value="All" selected>All</option>
              <option :value="item" v-for="item in menuArrayPrice">{{item}}</option>
            </select>
            <select name=""  class="form-control" v-model.trim="input.topics">
              <option value="All" selected>All</option>
              <option :value="item" v-for="item in menuArrayTopic">{{item}}</option>
            </select>
            <select name=""  class="form-control" v-model.trim="input.reviews">
              <option value="All" selected>All</option>
              <option :value="item" v-for="item in menuArrayReview">{{item}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input type="text" name=""  class="form-control" v-model.trim="input.topic" placeholder="search topics">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container w-75 mb-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" v-for="item in filterAry" >
          <ul class="course list-group mb-3">
            <li class="list-group-item text-accent h4 font-weight-bold">{{item.location}}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item text-secondary song-item d-flex flex-column ">
              {{item.topic}}{{item.price}}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the `filterAry` function to check each filter condition one by one as given below

```js
let classes = {
  menu: [
    { topic: 'math', location: 'adadadas', price: 80, length: "120", time: "9:00", reviewStars: "3" },
    { topic: 'math', location: 'dsadassa', price: 90, length: "70", time: "11:00", reviewStars: "4" },
    { topic: 'math', location: 'dadass', price: 120, length: "30", time: "14:00", reviewStars: "1" },
    { topic: 'english', location: 'dasdsadas', price: 110, length: "45", time: "13:00", reviewStars: "2" },
    { topic: 'english', location: 'fsafasf', price: 90, length: "75", time: "11:00", reviewStars: "4" },
    { topic: 'english', location: 'fafasa', price: 90, length: "100", time: "17:00", reviewStars: "2" },
    { topic: 'english', location: 'fsasada', price: 130, length: "90", time: "15:00", reviewStars: "3" },
    { topic: 'piano', location: 'dsadsadsads', price: 120, length: "", time: "50", time: "13:00", reviewStars: "4" },
    { topic: 'piano', location: 'dsadasddsadsadas', price: 140, length: "40", time: "12:00", reviewStars: "1" }
  ],
  input: {
    topic: '',
    location: 'All',
    topics: 'All',
    price: 'All',
    reviews: 'All'
  },
  newAry: [],
  otherAry: [],
  filterText: null
};


var searchBar = new Vue({
  el: '#searchBar',
  data: classes,
  computed: {
    menuArray() {
      let vm = this
      let array = new Set()
      vm.menu.forEach(function (item) {
        array.add(item.location)
      })
      console.log(array)
      return vm.newAry = Array.from(array)

    },

    menuArrayReview() {
      let vm = this
      let array = new Set()
      vm.menu.forEach(function (item) {
        array.add(item.reviewStars)
      })
      console.log(array)
      return vm.newAry = Array.from(array)

    },
    menuArrayTopic() {
      let vm = this
      let array = new Set()
      vm.menu.forEach(function (item) {
        array.add(item.topic)
      })
      console.log(array)
      return vm.newAry = Array.from(array)

    },
    menuArrayPrice() {
      let vm = this
      let array = new Set()
      vm.menu.forEach(function (item) {
        array.add(item.price)
      })
      console.log(array)
      return vm.newAry = Array.from(array)

    },

    filterTypeTopic() {
      let vm = this
      if (vm.input.topic !== 'All') {
        return vm.otherAry.filter(function (item) {
          return item.topic === vm.input.topic
        })
      } else {
        return vm.otherAry
      }
    },

    filterTypePrice() {
      let vm = this
      if (vm.input.price !== 'All') {
        return vm.otherAry.filter(function (item) {
          return item.price === vm.input.price
        })
      } else {
        return vm.otherAry
      }
    },

    filterTypeReviews() {
      let vm = this
      if (vm.input.review !== 'All') {
        return vm.otherAry.filter(function (item) {
          return item.reviewStars === vm.input.review
        })
      } else {
        return vm.otherAry
      }
    },

    filterAryTopic() {
      let vm = this
      if (vm.input.topic) {
        return vm.filterTypeTopic().filter(function (item) {
          let content = item.topic.toLowerCase()
          let keyword = vm.input.topic.toLowerCase()
          return content.indexOf(keyword) !== -1
        })
      } else {
        return vm.filterTypeTopic
      }

    },

    filterAryPrice() {
      let vm = this
      if (vm.input.price) {
        return vm.filterTypePrice.filter(function (item) {
          let content = item.price.toLowerCase()
          let keyword = vm.input.price.toLowerCase()
          return content.indexOf(keyword) !== -1
        })
      } else {
        return vm.filterTypePrice
      }

    },

    filterAryReviews() {
      let vm = this
      if (vm.input.review) {
        return vm.filterTypeReviews().filter(function (item) {
          let content = item.reviewStars.toLowerCase()
          let keyword = vm.input.review.toLowerCase()
          return content.indexOf(keyword) !== -1
        })
      } else {
        vm.menu = vm.filterTypeReviews()
      }
    },

    filterType() {
      let vm = this
      if (vm.input.location !== 'All') {
        return vm.otherAry.filter(function (item) {
          return item.location === vm.input.location
        })
      } else {
        return vm.menu
      }
    },

    filterAry() {
      let vm = this
      return vm.menu.filter(function(value){
        if(vm.input.topics.length && vm.input.topics!="All" && value.topic!=vm.input.topics) return false  
        if(vm.input.reviews.length && vm.input.reviews!="All" && value.reviewStars!=vm.input.reviews) return false  
        if(vm.input.price && vm.input.price!="All" && value.price!=vm.input.price) return false 
        if(vm.input.topic.length){
          return value.topic.indexOf(vm.input.topic) > -1
        }
      return true
      })
      
    },


    getAry() {
      let vm = this
      return vm.otherAry
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    newAry = classes;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="searchBar">
    <div class="display-3 text-center my-5 text-secondary">Activities!  </div>
    <div class="container w-75">
      <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div>
            <select name=""  class="form-control" v-model.trim="input.price">
              <option value="All" selected>All</option>
              <option :value="item" v-for="item in menuArrayPrice">{{item}}</option>
            </select>
            <select name=""  class="form-control" v-model.trim="input.topics">
              <option value="All" selected>All</option>
              <option :value="item" v-for="item in menuArrayTopic">{{item}}</option>
            </select>
            <select name=""  class="form-control" v-model.trim="input.reviews">
              <option value="All" selected>All</option>
              <option :value="item" v-for="item in menuArrayReview">{{item}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input type="text" name=""  class="form-control" v-model.trim="input.topic" placeholder="search topics">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container w-75 mb-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" v-for="item in filterAry" >
          <ul class="course list-group mb-3">
            <li class="list-group-item text-accent h4 font-weight-bold">{{item.location}}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item text-secondary song-item d-flex flex-column ">
              {{item.topic}}{{item.price}}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I've spent well over 5 hours on this and it was such a simple thing :')

Comment: Welcome. Keep practicing.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you've tried to do here, but I think you need to get a new and fresh look at it. Chaining filters would be correct aproach here, just need to get it working it right with your data set.

Probably this type of architecture would work

```js
data() {
  return {
    topic: 'All',
    location: 'All',
    // and rest of filterable parameters
  }
},

computed: {
    filteredAry () {
      const { topic, location } = this
      const filteredMenu = Array.from(menu);
      if (topic !== 'All') {
        filteredMenu.filter(item => item.topic === topic)
      }
      // ... and so on for all possible filter values
      return filteredMenu
    },
  },
```

and then you use `filteredAry` in your `v-for` loop to display data